# Rails - dynamic routes inside an each block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my first rails project and I'm a complete newbie to all code, not just Ruby, so please forgive me if I don't explain my issue concisely.

I have a model, Car, which belongs to another model, User. I want my Cars index page to show all cars in the database, so I made a custom route of '/cars/', rather than the :user_id/cars/:id route generated by Rails.

The Car info is getting output onto my index page, but I can't work out how to generate links back to the Car show page.

I'm sure it's something simple, but I've been reading the Rails Guide and other questions on here all day and haven't fixed it yet.

Here's the block:

```
                <% @cars.each do |car| %>                   
                <li>
                    <div class="well row <%= cycle('', 'white-bg')  %>">
                        <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
                            <!-- thumbnail for car here -->
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <%= link_to car.id, user_car_path(@user, car) do %>
                                <h3><%= car.year %> <%=car.make %> <%= car.model %></h3>
                            <% end %>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h3 class="pull-right"><%= car.price %></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>                   
            <% end %>
```

Routes:

```
get 'cars' => 'cars#index', as: :cars

resources :users do
    resource :profile
    resources :cars, except: :index
end
```

end

Controller:

```
def new
    @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    @car = @user.cars.build
end

# POST request to /users/:user_id/cars
def create
    @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    @car = @user.cars.build( car_params )
    if @car.save
        redirect_to user_path( params[:user_id] )
    end
end

# GET request to /users/:user_id/cars/:id
def show
    @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    @car = @user.cars.find( params[:id] )
end

# GET request to /cars/
def index
    @cars = Car.all
end
```

The error is:
        No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"cars", :id=>"1", :user_id=>nil} missing required keys: [:user_id]

I'm guessing I'm missing something in the controller, but everything I've tried in there just generates other errors.

Thanks!

cars_path   GET /cars(.:format) cars#index

POST    /cars(.:format) cars#create

new_car_path    GET /cars/new(.:format) cars#new

edit_car_path   GET /cars/:id/edit(.:format)    cars#edit

car_path    GET /cars/:id(.:format) cars#show

PATCH   /cars/:id(.:format) cars#update

PUT /cars/:id(.:format) cars#update

DELETE  /cars/:id(.:format) cars#destroy

new_user_profile_path   GET /users/:user_id/profile/new(.:format)
profiles#new

edit_user_profile_path  GET /users/:user_id/profile/edit(.:format)
profiles#edit

user_profile_path   GET /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)
profiles#show

PATCH   /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)   profiles#update

PUT /users/:user_id/profile(.:format) profiles#update

DELETE  /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)   profiles#destroy

POST    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)   profiles#create

user_cars_path  GET /users/:user_id/cars(.:format)  cars#index

POST    /users/:user_id/cars(.:format)  cars#create

new_user_car_path   GET /users/:user_id/cars/new(.:format)  cars#new

GET /cars/:id/edit(.:format)    cars#edit

GET /cars/:id(.:format) cars#show

PATCH   /cars/:id(.:format) cars#update

PUT /cars/:id(.:format) cars#update

DELETE  /cars/:id(.:format) cars#destroy

Comment: Could you please post the result of running `rake routes`?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your response earlier. I've added the current routes to the OP, though they're different from when I posted the question since I have followed Max's advice below. Still not quite up and running, so if you can help I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest an alternative solution where you "unnest" the cars resource - and just provide a index route for the cars belonging to a certain user:

```
# routes.rb
resources :cars
resources :users do
  resources :cars, module: 'users', only: [:index]
end
```

---

```
# app/controller/cars_controller.rb
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /cars
  def index
    @cars = Car.all
  end

  # show, create, delete, new...
end

# app/controller/users/cars_controller.rb
class Users::CarsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users/:user_id/cars
  def index
    @user = User.includes(:cars).find(params[:user_id])
    @cars = @user.cars
  end
end
```

Depending on the context you can move more of the collection routes (new, create) to `Users::CarsController` if you for example are able to create cars for other users. Nesting member routes (that act on a single record) 
is seldom necessary. You can avoid it by using the `shallow: true` option:

```
resources :users do
  resources :cars, shallow: true  
end
```

This lets you route to a car by simply doing:

```
link_to(@car.name, car_path(@car))
# or
link_to(@car.name, @car)
```

If you decide to keep your current setup you route to nested resource by using an array or keywords:

```
link_to(@car.name, user_car_path(user: @user, id: @car))
# or
link_to(@car.name, [@user, @car])
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply.

Comment: The idea of the site is that users sign up and list cars, like AutoTrader, so I'd like there to be: a profile page for each user which only shows cars belonging to that user, an index of all users linking to their profiles and an index for all cars. I have the first two, but having trouble with the third - hence the question.

Comment: Would you still recommend unnesting, given the above context?

Comment: Yes. Defiantly. I would use three controllers `Users`, `Cars` and `Users::Cars`. That gives you three separate index routes and a very clear devision of responsibility.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. I'll give it a whirl and will come back to mark this as answered when I get it working.

Comment: Hi again. I've followed everything as above but still get an error message on /cars/. Error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"cars", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Comment: Are you sure that `@car` is not nil? OR whatever variable you are using?

Comment: It is,  but I'm not sure why... With the nested set up I had earlier, the car id was getting populated in the URL, but the user_id wasn't.

Comment: All sorted - had to step away for a few mins to be able to look at it clearly. Thanks for your help.