# " Couldn't find User with 'id'= "

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I submitted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192611/rails-dynamic-routes-inside-an-each-block) yesterday and was mostly able to get the issue solved from the answers I got there, however I'm now having a different but related problem.

I have this code in my show view for my object, Car:

```
            <%= link_to @user do %>             
                <%= image_tag @user.profile.avatar.url, class: 'user-index-avatar' %>               
            <h3><%= @user.profile.company %></h3>
            <% end %>
            <h4><%= @user.profile.location %></h4>
            <h4><%= @user.profile.phone_number %></h4>
            <h4><%= @user.profile.email %></h4>
            <% if user_signed_in? && @user.id == current_user.id %>
            <%= link_to "Edit Listing", edit_car_path(id: @car.id ), class: 'btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block' %>
            <% end %>
```

When I go to this page, I get the error message "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in CarsController#show" and "Couldn't find User with 'id'="

Rake routes:

```
                cars GET    /cars(.:format)                        cars#index
                     GET    /cars(.:format)                        cars#index
                     POST   /cars(.:format)                        cars#create
             new_car GET    /cars/new(.:format)                    cars#new
            edit_car GET    /cars/:id/edit(.:format)               cars#edit
                 car GET    /cars/:id(.:format)                    cars#show
                     PATCH  /cars/:id(.:format)                    cars#update
                     PUT    /cars/:id(.:format)                    cars#update
                     DELETE /cars/:id(.:format)                    cars#destroy
    new_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/new(.:format)  profiles#new
   edit_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile/edit(.:format) profiles#edit
        user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#show
                     PATCH  /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#update
                     PUT    /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#update
                     DELETE /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#destroy
                     POST   /users/:user_id/profile(.:format)      profiles#create
           user_cars GET    /users/:user_id/cars(.:format)         cars#index
                     POST   /users/:user_id/cars(.:format)         cars#create
        new_user_car GET    /users/:user_id/cars/new(.:format)     cars#new
                     GET    /cars/:id/edit(.:format)               cars#edit
                     GET    /cars/:id(.:format)                    cars#show
                     PATCH  /cars/:id(.:format)                    cars#update
                     PUT    /cars/:id(.:format)                    cars#update
                     DELETE /cars/:id(.:format)                    cars#destroy
```

Models:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :plan
has_one :profile
has_many :cars
```

Routes.rb

```
get 'cars' => 'cars#index', as: :cars
resources :cars
resources :users do
    resource :profile
    resources :cars, shallow: true  
end
```

CarsController:

```
    def show
    @car = Car.find( params[:id] )
    @user = User.find( params[:user_id] )
    @profile = @user.profile
    end
```

The error specifies the issue is with "@user = User.find( params[:user_id] )", but I'm not sure how else to define @user. As mentioned in the linked problem above, I'm a complete newbie, so please forgive me if this is an obvious fix.

Comment: What user are you trying to get? The logged in one or the owner of the car?

Comment: The owner of the Car. I'm trying to link back to the user who posted the Car.

Comment: You can get that with `@car.user`

Comment: That same code previously worked when I was using nested routes as in the previous question I linked to, but I can't figure out how to get it to work now.

Comment: It would work with nested routes yes, since then there would be a `params[:user_id]` to use in your query.

Comment: Would I add that to the CarsController?

Comment: You have to change your routes first

Comment: Working with nested routes was giving me this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192611/rails-dynamic-routes-inside-an-each-block

Comment: @car.user worked - thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails find method raises this exception when it is unable to find a record by a specified id. You can double check your user_id in params and see if that id's record actually exists in database.

And by the error you have pasted, it seems user_id is null in your params.
You can always do some thing like

```
puts "Look for me in console\n"*10
puts params.inspect
```

And than see in the log window what params you are actually receiving.

I see your problem is solved in comments by accessing user association in car model, but this answer is intended to point to the root of problem and decrease number of unanswered question in SO :)